# Getting selected item of ng repeat on a datalist

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a array iteration to know which is the selected option. I'm insterested on id atribute of result. is there other way?

```
<input type="text" list="products" ng-model="query" />

<datalist id="products">                                        
    <option value="{{result.name}}" ng-repeat="result in results"  >
</datalist>
```

...

```
$scope.search = function (query) {
  $scope.results.forEach(function (result) {
    if (result.name === query) {
       // code here
    }
  }
}
```

...

Comment: Can you create a plunker as well?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<datalist id="products">                                        
    <option value="{{result.name}}" ng-selected="query.id == result.id" ng-repeat="result in results"  >
</datalist>
```